# Usage of なる with transitive verb

Tags: particles, transitivity

I'm currently struggling with particles in the following sentence:

。。。。、日本語が話せる機会を見つけづらくなると思います。

I want it to say that I think it will be become difficult to find opportunities where I am able to speak Japanese. The を is where I am in doubt. 見つける is transitive and なる is intransitive, and I don't know which one dictates the particle in this sentence.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

transitive verb 見つける→機会を is *find opportunities*
づらい　is *difficult*,
so, （機会を見つける）**づらい** is ***difficult*** to find opportunities
intransitive なる,
so, (機会を見つけづらく)**なる** is ***become*** difficult to find opportunities

Comment: Right. So I take it that the sentence is grammatically correct as it is?

Comment: @Deven: The given Japanese sentence is grammatically correct to perfection as it is.